# Laravel set DB field into an empty array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a field in my DB table where i set it as an array using json_encode. The field is called categories, where i input one or more category for a book. As follows:

```
$book->categories = json_encode($request->input('categories'));
```

Now my question is, when i try to update the categories with an empty array, i get an error. I tried to set the default value to null and then just pass null in my request

```
$book->categories = null;
```

But that didn't change anything in the DB. How can i update this field with an empty array??

Comment: update your question with the update code also lil bit more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:

```
if($request->input('categories')==null)
$book->categories=[];
else
book->categories = json_encode($request->input('categories'));
```